# Is there a way to change this view into a rectangle instead of what it currently is?

Tags: java, android, overlay

This is the code.

```
package com.gif.gif;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;;




public class recordScreen extends Service {

    LinearLayout oView;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        oView = new LinearLayout(this);
        oView.setBackgroundColor(0x88ff0000); // The translucent red color
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                0 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.addView(oView, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(oView!=null){
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            wm.removeView(oView);
        }
    }

}
```

This code generates the the following overlay on the app.

[image: Overlay Picture]

As you can see it places a red overlay over the app, my question is, is it possible to turn this overlay from a full overlay encompassing the screen into a rectangle? that is resizable?

how do we go about doing it?

Comment: Literally everything, it got to the point where my teamates and I gave up and came up with a new app idea... :l if you could solve it that would be nice to know, but it is no longer required.

Comment: Well my first guess would be use actual values for Width and Height when constructing the layout params instead of MATCH_PARENT, but of course you tried that since you tried _literally_ everything :P

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this things in the xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button3"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```